# Mysql split column into multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like:

```
  id  |  cat  |  price
----------------------
  0   |   1   |  2
  0   |   2   |  1 
  0   |   1   |  1
  1   |   1   |  31
  1   |   2   |  5
----------------------
```

I like to select it like:

```
  id  |  cat1_price  |  cat2_price  
----------------------------------
  0   |       3      |      1
  1   |      31      |      5
----------------------------------
```

My query so far:

```
SELECT SUM(`price`) as cat1_price FROM price_table WHERE cat = 1 GROUP BY id
```

which works to get one of the needed columns. **How can I have both?**

I also tried something like:

```
 SELECT SUM(`price`) as cat1_price 
(SELECT SUM(`price`) FROM price_table WHERE cat = 2) as cat2_price
 FROM price_table WHERE cat = 1 GROUP BY id
```

which works too slow. The actual table is pretty big and has some some joins.

I'm not sql guru, so I hope there is a query for this I'm not aware of :)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? (the separate columns bit, I mean)

Comment: its only for a visible (sortable) table output

Comment: A sortable table? - you mean the kind of thing that's done with ajax and php?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT id, SUM(case when cat = 1 then `price` else 0 end) as cat1_price,
       SUM(case when cat = 2 then `price` else 0 end) as cat1_price
FROM price_table
GROUP BY id;
```